# Remove display:none from slideToggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am using `slideToggle` jQuery function.which  adds `display: none` to the element.

But i need to `add/remove classes(.displayNone/.displayBlock`) instead of adding `style="display:block/display:none` to the element.

How to achieve it?.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').slideToggle('normal');
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h2p4myc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$('p').toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');////Adds 'displayNone', removes 'displayBlock' and vice versa
```

You need to add class to p element:

```
<p class="displayBlock">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0h2p4myc/2/)

> If you want **animation**: use `opicity` ans `transition` together,
>   because `display:none` does not work with `transition`.

Here is demo:

[**Transition Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0h2p4myc/3/)

### Update

---

Animation with added and removing class with `callback` function of slide toogle:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').slideToggle('normal',function(){ $(this).toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');});
})
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3t3Lvzpk/)

Comment: This demo has no animation.. But I need it

Comment: thanks for help, but I need add exactly display:none/block instead of opacity.

Comment: @user3724896 you can use `visibility:hidden;` and `visibility:visible;` instead of `display:none;` See demo http://jsfiddle.net/epspb888/

Comment: thanks! Helped. Also i needed to remove style attribute, when class added. I updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3t3Lvzpk/1/

Comment: This post does not answer the issue of `slideToggle` adding `display:none` / `display:block`. Also there is a better solution than removing the `style` attribute. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38259757/48492

Answer (score 4):

You need to add one class in the beginning to element and use `toggleClass()` instead:

```
$('p').toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xwpsf45h/)**

Comment: Not adding `displayBlock` class

Comment: @user3724896: display:none does not work for transition. see this http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties-. you should rather use slidetoggle to get desired effect.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I'm using slideToggle. But I need add display:none/block with class instead of 'style=""'..

Answer (score 0):

Manwal's answer did not include removing the `display:none` / `display:block` that `.slideToggle()` adds. Although `removeAttr('style')` works (as in the OP's [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t3Lvzpk/1)), it also resets any another inline styles on the element.

You can reset the `display` rule without affecting any other inline styles by setting it to `''`.

Here is a revised version:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').slideToggle('normal', function() {
      $(this).css('display', '').toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');
    });
});
```